# sqlalchemy- three entities joined via one table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following entities, each of which is a table in my database:

```
User
Application 
Role
```

I have another table called "user_app_role" which looks like this:

```
table user_app_role(
user_id int not null ,
application_id int not null,
role_id int not null,
primary key(user_id, application_id, role_id)
)
```

where user_id, application_id, and role_id are all foreign keys on the user, application, and role tables.

An entry in that table indicates that the user has a particular role within a particular application, so a row might return `1, 1, 1` indicating that user 1 has role 1 within application 1.  similarly, `1, 2, 1` would mean that user 1 also has role 2 within application 1.

I have sqlalchemy mappings defined for User, Application, and Role.  What I would like is for the User object to somehow have a list of Application objects and for each Application object, that object would contain a list of Role objects.

From reading the documentation for sqlalchemy, it appears this type of relationship is impossible to map and I have found only a few other questions on stackoverflow where this has been asked, none of which have an answer. This seems like a relatively normal 3NF database relationship (I have 4 of them in my whole data model), is it possible to somehow set this up in sqlalchemy?  I could do this whole thing in pure SQL in about 10 minutes but I don't want to throw away all the other useful feature of SqlAlchemy but if I can't make this somehow work, then my application will not be able to ship.

Also, PLEASE DO NOT suggest that just I alter my data model or denormalize the database or otherwise mess with that in any way.  Answers of that nature will not help me.  I'm happy to change my object model or add additional objects if I need to somehow magically map this one table to 2 objects or something weird like that but I am not able to change the data model.

Comment: I have still found no good solution for this but I did end up creating a separate UserAppRole object and used a relationship in my User object to join it to UserAppRole.  Since I can load the Application and Role objects (and there are very few of each) then my persistence layer just hooks up the values manually in those very rare cases when the id isn't enough (mostly for display in the UI somewhere).  I'll post an answer with more details if I haven't gotten a better answer over the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as far as I can determine, creating an actual mapping for this scenario is impossible in SqlAlchemy so here is my workaround:

```
class UserAppRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'userapprole'
    user_id = Column(stuff, ForeignKey(users.id))
    role_id = Column(otherstuff, ForeignKey(roles.id))
    app_id = Column(morestuff, ForeignKey(apps.id))
```

I've decided that in my application's domain, a User has roles with applications, so the relationship for this new object is going to be on the User:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    approles = relationship(UserAppRole, backref=backref('app_user_role', uselist=True))
    # other columns, relationships, etc.
```

This works well, because when I load a user I want to know what applications they have access to in any way and I want to know what roles they have for those applications.  In my domain, a Role is a thing and an Application is also a thing, and there are relatively few of those things and they tend not to change (although that isn't a requirement for this solution).  What's important is that I can load Application and Role objects by their ID, which conveniently enough I now have in my approles list in my User object.

To bind this all together, the last thing I do is use a repository to handle persistence for my User objects.  When I load a User, SqlAlchemy will populate the approles list with ID's.  I can then manually load the applications and roles and build a dictionary for applications with a list of roles.  Now when I add a role for a user to an application, I need to pass in the Application object (which knows what roles are valid) and a Role object (which may or may not be valid for that application).  Both of those will have ID's, so it's pretty trivial for me to update the dictionary and/or approles list to contain what I want.  In the unlikely event that I attempt to write to the DB with a role id or app id that doesn't exist, then the constraints in my database will reject the insert/update and I'll get an exception.

It's not my ideal solution, but it works quite well for the two situations that I'm encountering this.  If anyone has a better solution though, please post it.  I feel like composite adjacency lists ought to be useful for this scenario but the current SqlAlchemy documentation seems to indicate that these have to be for self-referencing tables and I haven't found a way to make this work for this particular scenario.